# How do I get the (integer) uid from the User entity?

Tags: 8, users

On the odd chance there was a "getUid()" method for the user entity, I tried it, but got:

> Call to undefined method Drupal\user\Entity\User::getUid()

Is there a way to get the uid from the user entity, without loading the full User object?

Comment: If you have the user entity, it's already loaded, and you can get the ID from it. Drupal 7: `$user->id` Drupal 8+: `$user->id()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the user entity, it's already loaded, and you can get the ID from it.

- Drupal 7

  ```
  $user->uid
  ```
- Drupal 8 and later

  ```
  $user->id()
  ```

Comment: This works also with the object returned from `\Drupal::currentUser()`. If the code wants to avoid to load the full User object, and it needs the ID for the currently logged user, that's the code to use. It doesn't seem the OP case, since the error is for `Drupal\user\Entity\User`, which means the code is trying to call `getUserId()` on a `Drupal\user\Entity\User` object, not a `Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxy` object. The _without loading the full User object_ part seems to contradict what the code is doing.